# No se suben las imágenes php upload

Tags: php, html

Quiero subir unas imágenes al servidor de mi web (que por el momento es local) me inserta bien el nombre de la imagen en la tabla pero el archivo no se mueve a la carpeta destinada para ello, este es mi codigo:

```
for($i = 1; $i < 7 ; $i++){
    $imagename = "image".$i;
    if ($_FILES[$imagename]['error'] > 0){
        echo "Error";
    } else {
        $limit_kb = 5000;
        if ($_FILES[$imagename]['size'] <= $limit_kb){
            $path = "res/user_uploads/".$_FILES[$imagename]['name'];
            if(!file_exists($path)){
                $imgresult = @move_uploaded_file ($_FILES[$imagename]['tmp_name'], $path);
                if($imgresult){
                    echo "ok";
                } else {
                    echo "no ok";
                }
            } else {
                echo $_FILES[$imagename]['name'].", this file alredy exists";
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Con este mismo código, como puedo hacer para que las imágenes subidas cambien de nombre como por ejemplo en vez de llamarse image20161102.jpg a llamarse image1.jpg ?

Comment: Prueba a imprimir la ruta y comprobar si es la misma en la cual quieres introducir los ficheros.

Comment: La ruta es correcta, se puede acceder desde el navegador a ella.

Comment: ¿Devuelve algún error `move_uploaded_file` (quita la @ para que lo muestre)? ¿La ruta existe? En cuyo caso ¿Tienes permisos de escritura?

Comment: No devuelve ningún error, teóricamente pasa todos los controles, y me guarda el nombre de la imagen en la base de datos (nombre de imagen ya pasado por todo el proceso que muestro arriba con el código aunque este no cambia ( no sé si esto debe ser así ) La ruta existe, y los permisos de escritura debería tenerlos ya que estoy en un pc windows.

Comment: Y la salida por pantalla es `ok` o `no ok` ??

Comment: La salida por pantalla es OK

Comment: TIenes permisos sobre esa carpeta? estas seguro de que la URL esta bien puesta? nombre y todo?

Comment: La url es correcta y la carpeta tiene permisos de escritura.

Comment: Cual es la salida de tu codigo? revisaste el maximo size que configuras en tu servidor?

Comment: Era por el size máximo.

Comment: El problema estaba en la línea del tammaño máximo del archivo.

Comment: Podrías extenderlo un poco más? Qué problema era?

Comment: @muriano  supongo que se refiere a `$limit_kb = 5000; `

Comment: Saludos! @PavloB.

Comment: Por defecto cada servidor establece un límite en el peso de los archivos. Los debes cambiar para que no ocurra este tipo de problemas, tanto desde el php.ini o con las variables de configuración, aunque algunos servidores (como los de hospedaje gratuitos) no te dejan manipular estos datos

Comment: Si, era por el limite de la variable $limit_kb = 5000;

Comment: He editado la pregunta porque me ha surgido otra duda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ten cuidado. Estás usando una ruta relativa para referenciar en donde quieres que se guarde la imagen. Si lo mantienes así, buscará la ruta que indiques en base al directorio en donde se encuentre el archivo. Si así no tienes estructurado los directorios, te dará error. En caso contrario debería funcionar sin problemas.

El arroba (`@`) que tienes previo al `move_uploaded_file` oculta cualquier error o warning que te genere el llamado a ese método, así que estuviera habiendo un error, deberías remover el arroba para poder leer la descripción del mismo.

Ahora, si quieres nombrar las imágenes con un indice incremental al término de las mismas,  podrías hacer algo como esto, en la asignación de la variable `$path`

```
$path = "res/user_uploads/image".$i.'.jpg';
```

En donde `$i` es el indice de tu ciclo `for`